# Students-t distribution and histogram overlay

Tags: r, overlay, histogram

Does anyone know why the t-distribution in the histogram overlay is just an horizontal line? The warnings() in fit.std result from the etimation of the dof, which can lead to an infinite likelihood - see Fernandez & Steel (1999).

```
library(zoo)
library(rugarch)

data(sp500ret)

g= zoo(sp500ret$SP500RET, as.Date(rownames(sp500ret)))
(fit.std = fitdistr(g,"t"))

mu.std = fit.std$estimate[["m"]]
lambda = fit.std$estimate[["s"]]
nu = fit.std$estimate[["df"]]

# plot
hist(g, density=20, breaks=20, prob=T)
curve(dt(x, nu, lambda), col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
```

[image]

Comment: You should always list all the packages you use. You left out 'MASS' to get the fitdistr function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help file for `fitdistr`:

> For the "t" named distribution the density is taken to be the location-scale family with location m and scale s.

For a location-scale family if we have a location parameter m and a scale parameter s then we can get the density at 'x' using the standardized version (location = 0, scale = 1, call it f) by using:

```
f((x-m)/s)/s
```

So for you we have mu.std is the location parameter and lambda is the scale so we would want to change your line to:

```
curve(dt((x-mu.std)/lambda, nu)/lambda, col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
```